# How to sort a collection of objects in JavaScript without converting it to an array

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I am trying to avoid writing my own sorting algorithm for the following use case:

```
avatars = {};
avatars[102] = {userInfo: {buddy_name: 'Avatar102', is_online: 1}};
avatars[100] = {userInfo: {buddy_name: 'Avatar100', is_online: 1}};
avatars[101] = {userInfo: {buddy_name: 'Avatar101', is_online: 1}};

console.log(_.keys(avatars));
avatars = _.sortBy(avatars, function(avatar) {return avatar.userInfo.buddy_name.toLowerCase();});
console.log(_.keys(avatars));
```

Here's the console output:

- ["102", "100", "101"]
- ["0", "1", "2"]

As you can see, with undescore's sortBy I am losing the key data. This struct can get very large, so I am trying to avoid things like converting to an array and then back to the collection. Is there any way to do this without rolling my own sort function?

Comment: Avatars is a Dictionary and unsorted by it's nature.
So, what exactly do you need? An ability to iterate over avatars in order?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your `avatars` is not an Array, it is just an object:

```
avatars = {};
```

so there is [no defined order for its elements](http://es5.github.io/#x12.6.4):

> The mechanics and order of enumerating the properties (step 6.a in the first algorithm, step 7.a in the second) is not specified.

and [15.2.3.7](http://es5.github.io/#x15.2.3.7) (and [15.2.3.14](http://es5.github.io/#x15.2.3.14)):

> If an implementation defines a specific order of enumeration for the for-in statement, that same enumeration order must be used to order the list elements in step 3 of this algorithm.

You can also check [section 8.6](http://es5.github.io/#x8.6) to see if there is any mention about the order of properties in an object. The only requirement for ordering of object properties is that if the implementation defines an order anywhere then it has to use that same ordering everywhere but that's a big *if*. Most implementations probably use insertion order for an object's keys but I can't find anything that requires them to (I'd appreciate a comment if anyone can point out anything in the specs that define any particular order of an object's keys).

That said, Underscore's [`sortBy`](http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy) is basically a [Schwartzian Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_Transform) combined with a standard JavaScript [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and Underscore's [`pluck`](http://underscorejs.org/#pluck) to unwrap the Schwartzian Transform memo wrappers; `pluck` returns an array so `sortBy` also returns an array. Hence, your final `_.keys(avatars)` call is actually calling [`_.keys`](http://underscorejs.org/#keys) on an array; the keys of an array (AKA enumerable properties) are the array's indices and those are consecutive integers starting at zero.

You're using the wrong data structure. If you need a sparse array but also need to manipulate it like an array (i.e. sort it), then you should put the indexes inside the objects and use a normal array and `pluck` instead of `keys`:

```
var avatars = [
    {idx: 102, userInfo: {buddy_name: 'Avatar102', is_online: 1}},
    {idx: 100, userInfo: {buddy_name: 'Avatar100', is_online: 1}},
    {idx: 101, userInfo: {buddy_name: 'Avatar101', is_online: 1}}
];
console.log(_(avatars).pluck('idx'));
avatars = _(avatars).sortBy(function(avatar) {
    return avatar.userInfo.buddy_name.toLowerCase();
});
console.log(_(avatars).pluck('idx'));
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/UCWL2/

If you also need quick access by `idx` then you could set up a parallel object for direct `idx` access:

```
var avatars_by_idx = { };
for(var i = 0; i < avatars.length; ++i)
    avatars_by_idx[avatars[i].idx] = avatars[i];
```

Then `avatars_by_idx` provides the direct access you're looking for. Of course, you'd have to keep `avatars` and `avatars_by_idx` synchronized but that's not terribly difficult if you hide them both behind an object.

Comment: thanks for the detailed response. Unfortunately I need to be able to quickly look up "records" in the avatars collection using the idx, so changing the data structure is not an option. Maybe it'd be better to create a new list used for the sorting...

Comment: @Rosco: If you're just working with the raw `avatars` data then use the `avatars` array as above as the main store and keep a separate object which maps the `idx` to objects in the `avatars` array. This extra `avatars_by_idx` object would serve the same purpose as an index in a database.

Comment: hmm - I was thinking the opposite - the data store would be the collection of objects keyed on idx, and the sorted array would only contain the idx ordered based on the buddy_name. I forgot to mention that new avatars are added to the struct after initialization...

Comment: Either way would probably work and if you hide both inside an object then you could add new entries through a method on that object and ensure that everything stays synchronized.