# Backbone view's model is missing, but I don't understand why

Tags: backbone.js

I'm having a simple but confusing problem. I have the following piece of code:

```
<div id="restaurant_locations"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    window.router = new Lunchhub.Routers.RestaurantLocationsRouter({
      restaurantLocations: <%= @restaurant_locations.to_json.html_safe -%>
    });
    Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
  });
</script>
```

which throws this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toJSON' of undefined
```

If I take out the `{pushState: true}` part, though, and just do `Backbone.history.start()` with no arguments, it works just fine.

Next to the error, it says `show_view.js: 19`. Here's what that part of `show_view.js` looks like:

```
    ShowView.prototype.template = JST["backbone/templates/restaurant_locations/show"];

    ShowView.prototype.render = function() {
      $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON())); // LINE 19
      Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toJSON' of undefined
      return this;
    }
```

So I guess `this.model` is undefined. Here's the `show_view` CoffeeScript:

```
Lunchhub.Views.RestaurantLocations ||= {}

class Lunchhub.Views.RestaurantLocations.ShowView extends Backbone.View
  template: JST["backbone/templates/restaurant_locations/show"]

  render: ->
    $(@el).html(@template(@model.toJSON() ))
    return this
```

If I can make `@model` be what it needs to be, I guess it might fix the problem. But I don't know where `@model` comes from or anything.

What do I need to do?

**Edit:** I got a little further. In the `show` function below, `id` is set to "restaurant_locations", and there's of course no member of `@restaurantLocations` with an id of `restuarant_locations`. The fact that `id` set set to `restaurant_locations` makes a certain amount of sense; the URL I'm hitting is `http://localhost:3000/restaurant_locations`. But it seems like it should be calling the `index` function, not `show`, if that's the URL to which I'm going.

```
class Lunchhub.Routers.RestaurantLocationsRouter extends Backbone.Router
  initialize: (options) ->
    @restaurantLocations = new Lunchhub.Collections.RestaurantLocationsCollection()
    @restaurantLocations.reset options.restaurantLocations

  routes:
    "new"      : "newRestaurantLocation"
    "index"    : "index"
    ":id/edit" : "edit"
    ":id"      : "show"
    ".*"        : "index"

  newRestaurantLocation: ->
    @view = new Lunchhub.Views.RestaurantLocations.NewView(collection: @restaurantLocations)
    $("#restaurant_locations").html(@view.render().el)

  index: ->
    @view = new Lunchhub.Views.RestaurantLocations.IndexView(restaurantLocations: @restaurantLocations)
    $("#restaurant_locations").html(@view.render().el)

  show: (id) ->
    restaurant_location = @restaurantLocations.get(id)

    @view = new Lunchhub.Views.RestaurantLocations.ShowView(model: restaurant_location)
    $("#restaurant_locations").html(@view.render().el)

  edit: (id) ->                   
    restaurant_location = @restaurantLocations.get(id)

    @view = new Lunchhub.Views.RestaurantLocations.EditView(model: restaurant_location)
    $("#restaurant_locations").html(@view.render().el)
```

Comment: `showVideo.model` comes from `new ShowView({ model: myModelInstance })`. Sorry but I have to say that if you don't know that you should start investigating with Backbone in much more simple scenarios.

Comment: Perhaps I should have mentioned: I'm on Rails and using the `backbone-rails` gem, which generates a lot of code automatically. I would expect it to work without me having to debug its generated code, but that hasn't turned out to be the case.

Comment: Also, I've found the offending line: `@view = new Lunchhub.Views.RestaurantLocations.ShowView(model: restaurant_location)`. In this case, `restaurant_location` is undefined, which is obviously not going to work. Now the question is why that variable is being set to the wrong thing. I'll post the relevant code in a little bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `id` is set to `"restaurant_locations"`, and there's of course no member of `@restaurantLocations` with an `id` of `"restuarant_locations"`.

Sounds like you have a routing problem so let us look at your routes:

```
routes:
  "new"      : "newRestaurantLocation"
  "index"    : "index"
  ":id/edit" : "edit"
  ":id"      : "show"
  ".*"       : "index"
```

I see several problems there. First of all, routes are not regexes so `".*"` doesn't match what `/.*/` does (i.e. any sequence of characters), it actually matches any number of periods (i.e. /^.*$/); you can run it through [`_routeToRegex`](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L948) yourself to see what happens to `'.*'`:

```
var namedParam    = /:\w+/g;
var splatParam    = /\*\w+/g;
var escapeRegExp  = /[-[\]{}()+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g;
//...
_routeToRegExp: function(route) {
  route = route.replace(escapeRegExp, '\\$&')
               .replace(namedParam, '([^\/]+)')
               .replace(splatParam, '(.*?)');
  return new RegExp('^' + route + '$');
},
```

The next problem is that `":id"` matches almost anything. `routeToRegexp` converts `":id"` to `/^([^/]+)$/`; that regex matches any non-empty sequence of non-slashes and in particular, that will match what most of your other routes match.

So when you expect to hit `'.*': 'index'` from `/restaurant_locations`, you're actually hitting `':id': 'show'` and you're getting lucky that `'/new'` and `'/index'` aren't also getting matched by `':id'`. Keep in mind that the order of elements in a (Java|Coffee)Script object is implementation defined so the order that they appear in in your source code really doesn't matter; many JavaScript implementations will respect the source order but never depend on it.

Since the route order doesn't matter, you have to look at your `routes` keys as a simple unordered set and you--the human--must ensure that your route patterns really do match distinct things. If you do need overlapping route patterns and you need them to get matched in a specific order, then you can use the [`route`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Router-route) method in your router's [`initialize`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Router-constructor) to manually add the routes (as routing patterns or regexes) in the required order.

---

**Executive Summary:** Fix your routes so that they match distinct things.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to fix the problem (that is, make the page load without errors) by adding a new route at the top: `"index" : "restaurant_locations"`. It seems that the route order does actually matter, since adding that new route at the bottom didn't do anything, but adding it at the top did.

Comment: @JasonSwett: Depending on the route order in the source is a gamble, there is absolutely no guarantee that it will work. By depending on the source order you are leaving yourself open to browser dependent bugs. The JavaScript standard does not guarantee that iterating over the keys of an object will yield the keys in source order (http://stackoverflow.com/a/10624559/479863).