# Why is my backbone router redirecting to the app root?

Tags: jquery-mobile, backbone.js, backbone-routing

I'm using the following router in my app:

```
app.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    // define the route and function maps for this router
    routes : {
        "" : "showLogin",
        // Sample usage: http://ServerManager/
        "login" : "login",
        // Sample usage: http://ServerManager/#login
        "logout" : "logout",
        // Sample usage: http://ServerManager/#logout
        "folders" : "listFolders",
        // Sample usage: http://ServerManager/#folders
        "folders/:name" : "showFolder",
        // Sample usage: http://ServerManager/#folders/System
        "*other" : "defaultRoute"
        // Sample usage: http://ServerManager/#badHash
    },
    showLogin : function() {
        console.log("Home page loaded. Redirecting to #login page.");
        this.navigate("login", {trigger: true, replace: true});
    },
    login : function() {
        //console.log("login route fired");
        // delete sessionStorage items and load a new loginview
        this.changePage(new app.LoginView()); 
    },
    logout : function() {
        //console.log("logout route fired");
        // Clear the token and other session items from sessionStorage
        sessionStorage.clear();
        this.navigate("login", {trigger: true, replace: true});
    },
    listFolders : function() {
        //console.log("listFolders route fired.")
        if (app.folderView === undefined) {
            console.log("creating new app.folderView");
            app.folderView = new app.FolderView();
        }
        else {
            console.log("using existing app.folderView");
        }
        this.changePage(app.folderView);
    },
    showFolder : function(name) {
        console.log( app.router.routes[Backbone.history.fragment] );
        //console.log("showFolder route fired.")
        this.changePage(new app.ServiceView({folder : name}));
        console.log( app.router.routes[Backbone.history.fragment] );
        //app.router.navigate("folder/" + name, {trigger: false});
    },
    defaultRoute : function() {
        alert("Error. Page doesn\'t exist.");
    },
    changePage : function(page) {
        $(page.el).attr("data-role", "page");
        page.render();
        $("body").append($(page.el));
        var transition = $.mobile.defaultPageTransition;
        $.mobile.changePage($(page.el), {changeHash : true, transition : transition});
    }
});
```

If I use

```
app.router.navigate("folders", {trigger: true, replace: true});
```

it successfully sends the app to server/#folders, but when I pass

```
app.router.navigate("folders/" + id, {trigger: true, replace: true});
```

it triggers the root of the app and loads my login page. I can see the correct URL (e.g. server/folders/folder1) temporarily flash before the redirect happens. Any ideas as to what's happening here?

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is but I think that the [jquery-mobile-router](https://github.com/azicchetti/jquerymobile-router) plugin was originally created because JQM didn't play nice with backbone.js.

Answer (score 1):

Backbone routers expect more generic routes last.

Set-up the `folders/:id` route followed by the `folders` route.

**UPDATE**

Actually, after thinking about it, this may not be the case. Can you post console output? Is it calling the correct function?

Perhaps the `$.mobile ... changeHash: true` is conflicting. You should probably only have one of the frameworks change the url hash for you.

Comment: I tried changing the order of the routes and setting changeHash to false, but same result. It temporarily loads the page, then redirects to the app root.

Comment: This "more generic routes last" stuff that used to be in the Backbone docs was nonsense, [there is no well defined key order in a JavaScript object](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10624559/479863). You'll notice that the Backbone router docs no longer say anything about the order of things in `routes` (at least I can't find it anymore).

Comment: OTOH, I think you might be right that jQuery Mobile and Backbone are fighting each other.

Comment: I've got all jqm routing and navigation disabled. If I comment out the navigate line in my router showLogin function then all works fine (except then it won't show the login page when I hit the root of the app).

Comment: @muistooshort the source still says that it follows the concept of "more generic routes last." In fact it only worked for me when I mapped rails routes to backbone in this manner, i.e. `posts/:id` AFTER `posts/new`

Comment: @Evan just map the `""` route to `login()` such that you don't even have a `showLogin()` function.

Comment: The source is mistaken about how JavaScript works, there is no well defined "last" in a JavaScript object. The only way to get your routes checked in a specific and reliable order is to add them manually by calling [`route`](http://backbonejs.org/#Router-route). Assuming that the source-order of things in `routes` means anything is a gamble that you will lose sooner or later.